# datalevin function expression re-binds variable

Tags: clojure, datomic, datascript

I am using Datalevin 0.8.16 as a database for my application. I have inserted some data:

```clj
(datalevin.core/transact! conn
  [{:hello "some value"
    :data {:k "other value"}}])
```

Then running the query:

```clj
  (datalevin.core/q
    '[:find ?e ?v
      :where [?e :hello ?v]
             [?e :data ?d]
             [(get ?d :k) ?v]]
    my-db)
```

The result is `#{[21 "other value"]}`.

I was expecting that the result set should have been empty, because usually the same `?v` variable cannot be bound to two different values.

Apparently, even though `?v` was bound to `"some value"`, it re-bound to `"other value"` in the following binding.

Is it expected behaviour or a bug? I did not found anything like this mentioned in the Datomic documentation of [Function Expressions](https://docs.datomic.com/pro/query/query.html#function-expressions), and it calls the second parameter a binding to a variable, which should behave as regular bindings.